# How to reduce stack space usage for Anchor programs?

Tags: anchor, error

It's common to run into these errors during compile time

```
Stack offset of 6344 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 2248 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
```

or these errors during run time

```
Program failed to complete: Access violation in stack frame 3 at address 0x200003fe0 of size 8 by instruction #28386
```

Both of these indicate that the stack space usage exceeds the Solana max of 4096 bytes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Box Accounts

`Box`ing accounts in `#[Accounts]` struct moves the account variables from the stack to the heap.

This however requires you to be able to deserialize the account with an `#[account]` type.

Eg

```
account: UncheckedAccount<'info>
```

becomes

```
account: Box<Account<'info, MyAccount>>
```

The trade-off is it will use more compute units to deserialize and validate the account data.

### remaining_accounts

If you can't `Box` and deserialize accounts (they're `SystemProgram` owned, or you're too lazy to write out the serialization format), then don't include the account explicitly in `#[Accounts]` and manually pull it out of `ctx.remaining_accounts` in the body.

### #[inline(never)]

The 4KB limit is on each **stack frame**. Each function call uses 1 stack frame, so if you have a beefy function it could very well exceed 4KB in stack space.

One trick is to break apart the function into sub-functions, then annotate the sub-functions with `#[inline(never)]` macro.

This

```
fn big() {
  // Do stuff 1
  // Do stuff 2
  // Do stuff 3
}
```

becomes

```
#[inline(never)]
fn stuff1() {
  // Do stuff 1
}

#[inline(never)]
fn stuff2() {
  // Do stuff 2
}

#[inline(never)]
fn stuff3() {
  // Do stuff 3
}

fn big() {
  stuff1();
  stuff2();
  stuff3();
}
```

### Boxing variables

If you have functions that allocate large structs, `Box::new()` will move them from the stack to the heap.